# Android firebase query multiple child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello guys I am trying to select courses which contain student of specific name, it may be because there are multiple students registered on a course, but I still can't solve that issue. (very similar query i.e. for course name works perfectly fine) Data snapshot looks like{key:course,value:null} even though there is course which should satisfy criteria [Firebase structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2MMv.png)

```
   Query query= mDatabase.child("courses").orderByChild("students/name").equalTo("Dominik Skoczylas");
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override

        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren())

                {
                    userCourse = child.getValue(Course.class);

                }
            }}
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });




  "courses" : {
"-Kfo-G37vwtUkWAv1zE_" : {
  "modules" : [ {
    "lectures" : [ {
      "endTime" : {
        "date" : 1,
        "day" : 4,
        "hours" : 1,
        "minutes" : 1,
        "month" : 1,
        "seconds" : 1,
        "time" : 1517446861000,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 118
      },
      "room" : {
        "name" : "J100"
      },
      "starTime" : {
        "date" : 1,
        "day" : 3,
        "hours" : 1,
        "minutes" : 1,
        "month" : 1,
        "seconds" : 1,
        "time" : 1485910861000,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 117
      },
      "topic" : "Distributed 1"
    }, {
      "endTime" : {
        "date" : 1,
        "day" : 4,
        "hours" : 1,
        "minutes" : 1,
        "month" : 1,
        "seconds" : 1,
        "time" : 1517446861000,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 118
      },
      "room" : {
        "name" : "J200"
      },
      "starTime" : {
        "date" : 1,
        "day" : 3,
        "hours" : 1,
        "minutes" : 1,
        "month" : 1,
        "seconds" : 1,
        "time" : 1485910861000,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 117
      },
      "topic" : "Distributed 2"
    } ],
    "name" : "Distributed computing"
  }, {
    "lectures" : [ {
      "endTime" : {
        "date" : 1,
        "day" : 4,
        "hours" : 1,
        "minutes" : 1,
        "month" : 1,
        "seconds" : 1,
        "time" : 1517446861000,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 118
      },
      "room" : {
        "name" : "J100"
      },
      "starTime" : {
        "date" : 1,
        "day" : 3,
        "hours" : 1,
        "minutes" : 1,
        "month" : 1,
        "seconds" : 1,
        "time" : 1485910861000,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 117
      },
      "topic" : "Advanced 1"
    }, {
      "endTime" : {
        "date" : 1,
        "day" : 4,
        "hours" : 1,
        "minutes" : 1,
        "month" : 1,
        "seconds" : 1,
        "time" : 1517446861000,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 118
      },
      "room" : {
        "name" : "J200"
      },
      "starTime" : {
        "date" : 1,
        "day" : 3,
        "hours" : 1,
        "minutes" : 1,
        "month" : 1,
        "seconds" : 1,
        "time" : 1485910861000,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 117
      },
      "topic" : "Advanced 2"
    } ],
    "name" : "Advanced internet"
  }, {
    "lectures" : [ {
      "endTime" : {
        "date" : 1,
        "day" : 4,
        "hours" : 1,
        "minutes" : 1,
        "month" : 1,
        "seconds" : 1,
        "time" : 1517446861000,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 118
      },
      "room" : {
        "name" : "J100"
      },
      "starTime" : {
        "date" : 1,
        "day" : 3,
        "hours" : 1,
        "minutes" : 1,
        "month" : 1,
        "seconds" : 1,
        "time" : 1485910861000,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 117
      },
      "topic" : "Concurrent 1"
    }, {
      "endTime" : {
        "date" : 1,
        "day" : 4,
        "hours" : 1,
        "minutes" : 1,
        "month" : 1,
        "seconds" : 1,
        "time" : 1517446861000,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 118
      },
      "room" : {
        "name" : "J200"
      },
      "starTime" : {
        "date" : 1,
        "day" : 3,
        "hours" : 1,
        "minutes" : 1,
        "month" : 1,
        "seconds" : 1,
        "time" : 1485910861000,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 117
      },
      "topic" : "Concurrent 2"
    } ],
    "name" : "Concurrent programming"
  } ],
  "name" : "Software Engineering",
  "students" : [ {
    "name" : "Dominik Skoczylas"
  }, {
    "name" : "Marta Mleczko"
  }, {
    "name" : "Zenon Zenon"
  }, {
    "name" : "Matt Damon"
  } ]
},
"-Kfo-G3G4ndKYpKHhtgV" : {
  "modules" : [ {
    "lectures" : [ {
      "endTime" : {
        "date" : 1,
        "day" : 4,
        "hours" : 1,
        "minutes" : 1,
        "month" : 1,
        "seconds" : 1,
        "time" : 1517446861000,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 118
      },
      "room" : {
        "name" : "J100"
      },
      "starTime" : {
        "date" : 1,
        "day" : 3,
        "hours" : 1,
        "minutes" : 1,
        "month" : 1,
        "seconds" : 1,
        "time" : 1485910861000,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 117
      },
      "topic" : "Concurrent 1"
    }, {
      "endTime" : {
        "date" : 1,
        "day" : 4,
        "hours" : 1,
        "minutes" : 1,
        "month" : 1,
        "seconds" : 1,
        "time" : 1517446861000,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 118
      },
      "room" : {
        "name" : "J200"
      },
      "starTime" : {
        "date" : 1,
        "day" : 3,
        "hours" : 1,
        "minutes" : 1,
        "month" : 1,
        "seconds" : 1,
        "time" : 1485910861000,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 117
      },
      "topic" : "Concurrent 2"
    } ],
    "name" : "Concurrent programming"
  }, {
    "lectures" : [ {
      "endTime" : {
        "date" : 1,
        "day" : 4,
        "hours" : 1,
        "minutes" : 1,
        "month" : 1,
        "seconds" : 1,
        "time" : 1517446861000,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 118
      },
      "room" : {
        "name" : "J100"
      },
      "starTime" : {
        "date" : 1,
        "day" : 3,
        "hours" : 1,
        "minutes" : 1,
        "month" : 1,
        "seconds" : 1,
        "time" : 1485910861000,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 117
      },
      "topic" : "Graphics 1"
    }, {
      "endTime" : {
        "date" : 1,
        "day" : 4,
        "hours" : 1,
        "minutes" : 1,
        "month" : 1,
        "seconds" : 1,
        "time" : 1517446861000,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 118
      },
      "room" : {
        "name" : "J200"
      },
      "starTime" : {
        "date" : 1,
        "day" : 3,
        "hours" : 1,
        "minutes" : 1,
        "month" : 1,
        "seconds" : 1,
        "time" : 1485910861000,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 117
      },
      "topic" : "Graphics 2"
    } ],
    "name" : "Graphics"
  }, {
    "lectures" : [ {
      "endTime" : {
        "date" : 1,
        "day" : 4,
        "hours" : 1,
        "minutes" : 1,
        "month" : 1,
        "seconds" : 1,
        "time" : 1517446861000,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 118
      },
      "room" : {
        "name" : "J100"
      },
      "starTime" : {
        "date" : 1,
        "day" : 3,
        "hours" : 1,
        "minutes" : 1,
        "month" : 1,
        "seconds" : 1,
        "time" : 1485910861000,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 117
      },
      "topic" : "Artificial 1"
    }, {
      "endTime" : {
        "date" : 1,
        "day" : 4,
        "hours" : 1,
        "minutes" : 1,
        "month" : 1,
        "seconds" : 1,
        "time" : 1517446861000,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 118
      },
      "room" : {
        "name" : "J200"
      },
      "starTime" : {
        "date" : 1,
        "day" : 3,
        "hours" : 1,
        "minutes" : 1,
        "month" : 1,
        "seconds" : 1,
        "time" : 1485910861000,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 117
      },
      "topic" : "Artificial 2"
    } ],
    "name" : "Artificial intelligence"
  } ],
  "name" : "Computer Science",
  "students" : [ {
    "name" : "Leonardo Dicaprio"
  }, {
    "name" : "John Lennon"
  }, {
    "name" : "Anthony Bond"
  }, {
    "name" : "Andy Jones"
  } ]
}
```

}

Comment: It's helpful if you could post your data structure as text rather than a screenshot. Simply export data as a JSON file from Firebase console and add it to your question.

Comment: Check my answer on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46156902/make-firebaserecycleradapter-get-data-under-conditions-and-not-all-of-them/46384299#46384299