# Make FirebaseRecyclerAdapter get data under conditions and not all of them

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to adjust somehow the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter in order to get some data from my database and not all of them. Is there any way to achieve that? My end goal is to show 10 random entries on the screen! Here is what I tried and the results:

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Houses, HousesViewHolder> mHousesRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Houses, HousesViewHolder>(
                Houses.class,
                R.layout.house_single,
                HousesViewHolder.class,
                mDatabaseHouses
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(HousesViewHolder viewHolder, Houses house, int position) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(house.getPrice()) > 200) {
                    viewHolder.setHouseName(house.getHouse_name());
                    viewHolder.setCity(house.getCity());
                    viewHolder.setImage(house.getMainFoto(), getApplicationContext());
                    viewHolder.setPrice(house.getPrice());
                }

            }
        };

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mHousesRecyclerAdapter);
```

[image]

The entries with the google logo are the houses that have price < 200 and are the houses in this example that I do not them to be appeared at all.

Single House XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/single_house_image"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/single_house_name_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="House Name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/single_house_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/single_house_location_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="House Location "
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/single_house_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/single_house_name_tv" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/single_house_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:text="Price"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/single_house_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/single_house_location_tv" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Why don't you use firebase queries?. It is efficient and simple but quit limited.

Comment: Do you need ONLY those houses which have a price greater than 200? Or any XX value?

Comment: @AtifFarrukh right know I need only that but ideally I would like to display any house any meets  some conditions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a ListView instead of this firebaserecycler. Check an example:

```
List<YourObject> mylist = new ArrayList<YourObject>();

database.child("houses").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                 //Filter your data
                 String name = postSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                 if(name.equals("test") {
                     YourObject myObject = new YourObject(name);
                     mylist.add(myObject);
                 }
             }

             updatelist();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError2) {

        }
 });
```

Update your listview

```
 void updatelist() {
     ListView yourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);

     // get data from the table by the HousesAdapter
     YourAdapter customAdapter = new YourAdapter(YourClass.this, R.layout.adapter_layout, mylist);

     yourListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
 }
```

An adapter example:

```
public class YourAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<YourObject> {
    Context context;

    public YourAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Houses> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        YourObject yourObject = getItem(position);

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.adapter_layout, null);
        }

        TextView mytextview = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
        mytextview.setText(yourObject.getName());

        return v;
    }
}
```

YourObject class

```
public class YourObject {
    private String name;

    public YourObject(String name) {
         this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

 }
```

Layout

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
 </ListView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can achieve this by key bases,

**Logic :**

You have to create key like "from_database", When you will get data from database you can just add extra key from_database = true, on the other hand you can add from server from_database= false.

After that you can use method getviewtype() and pass type 0 : 1 on the bases of from_database key and you can exactly what you want .

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I kind of see what you are saying to me but I am having difficulties implementing your idea. Do you have any examples that I could read?

Comment: Well the code it above, I just do not understand how I should modify it in order to get the houses the have a certain attribute for example show the houses that are only on a certain location. If a place a condition, which I do in the code above, I get that result which is not optimal :)

Answer (score 2):

In such situations I just make set the child Views visibility inside the ViewHolder to GONE, so they disappear if they do not match the case:

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Houses, HousesViewHolder> mHousesRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Houses, HousesViewHolder>(
                Houses.class,
                R.layout.house_single,
                HousesViewHolder.class,
                mDatabaseHouses
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(HousesViewHolder viewHolder, Houses house, int position) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(house.getPrice()) > 200) {
                    viewHolder.setHouseName(house.getHouse_name());
                    viewHolder.setCity(house.getCity());
                    viewHolder.setImage(house.getMainFoto(), getApplicationContext());
                    viewHolder.setPrice(house.getPrice());
                } else {
                    viewHolder.childView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    // repeat this for each childView inside your ViewHolder
                    ...
                }
            }
        };

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mHousesRecyclerAdapter);
```

This will work, but make sure that your item_view.xml which contains all the views from ViewHolder has appropriate setting of height:  `layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: Your logic is good but unfortunately is does not work. True it does not appear the house but there is "white space" between the houses if a house has not been rendered.

Comment: Check your item_layout.xml file (I believe it's house_single.xml in your case). Look at ALL the Views inside it including your root view. Make sure that the layout_height attribute of each is set to wrap_content.

Comment: Also, make sure you don't have any padding/margin set for the root view, they'll create extra space.

Comment: Yes yes everything its wrap content. The thing is that the recycler know the number of ites so its created the required space and even if I set the visibility as GONE it will not change anything. Interesting idea though

Comment: It should work, I have similar apps where I use this logic and resize items as I wish. Can you provide your house_single.xml via an edit to the question.

Comment: Here is how it is being displayed: https://ibb.co/kk5udk
Yes I'll edit the answer on top with the XML

Comment: Oh cmon man) what's this: android:layout_height="120dp" inside your imageView? set it to wrap_content.

Comment: Seriously? Mate the image is contained on the layout and the layout is wrap_content. But ok I did it wrap content and obviously nothing changed, just the images got bigger. Thanks for your time but your approach is wrong.

Comment: Okay, than this is very strange. I just copied your layout and tried setting all views visibility to "gone". Everything works.

Comment: Show me a screenshot if possible.

Comment: I set the background color to red, so the View is visible: https://ibb.co/eZh1PQ After I add android:visibility="gone" : https://ibb.co/ekTVJk the view disappears completely.

Answer (score 0):

User Firebase `Query` to limit your results

```
Query query = database.child(FirebasePaths.HOUSES).orderByChild(PRICE).startAt(200);
```

This will query your database for houses whose prices are above 200.